# Order of UI operations on Android?

Tags: android, performance, optimization, user-interface

I've been building for Android for six months now, and I'm still confused about how things happen in the UI. When I learned iOS programming, the books and docs were very clear about what happened when: for instance, that view changes and animations didn't take effect until the next iteration through the run loop. This understanding is critical to debugging UI glitches, and without it I'm having trouble tracking stuff down in our Android app (http://emu.is/download/).

For instance:

- We had a situation where pressing a button brought up a fragment, and also displayed an animation as feedback for the button click. I started the animation before pulling in the fragment, yet it didn't actually run until after the fragment appeared. Why?
- Often, opening a new Activity will take a long time, during which the user doesn't have great feedback that anything is happening. I'd love to pull up a minimal container for the Activity, *then* load its content, so the user knows what's happening. How do I do that?
- Sometimes our chat bubbles (which are drawn programmatically via a custom Drawable) flash a bit, and it looks like they're being rendered halfway through their drawing process. Why? How do I avoid that?

And so forth. Basically I'd like to understand as much as possible about what happens when in the Android UI -- not just the lifecycle stuff that's well-documented, but the relationship between various UI calls and when/how things actually happen onscreen. Thanks.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Everything-and-the-kitchen-sink questions ("I'd like to understand as much as possible about what happens when in the Android UI") are not effective for StackOverflow, as nobody is going to sit here and write dozens of pages. Similarly, lumping independent topics (your three bullets) into a single question is less effective than having those be independent questions, as few people can necessarily help with all of those bullets, but might be able to help with one, particularly if you took the time to provide source code, etc.

Comment: Hmm...I suppose I was hoping folks might point me to blog posts, books, or other resources that might answer my question. I've seen a number of other useful SO posts that take that form. Alternatively, can you suggest a better place to ask this?

Comment: If "this" is your list of bulleted items, SO is a fine place, but break them up into three questions and provide adequate context, such as your code. If "this" is "Basically I'd like to understand...", I doubt that you will find a single source for all of this, in part because the answer has changed over the years. I would recommend that you watch all Google I|O conference presentations by Romain Guy (with or without Chet Haase) up on YouTube, particularly the 2012 and 2013 ones.

Comment: Thanks...that's exactly the answer I was looking for. I may come back and ask one or more of those individual questions after watching the videos, but at least one of them got resolved a different way (and, sadly, without my developing a better understanding of the underlying question).